# Port ACLs, users and groups from one AEM instance to another?

Tags: aem

What is the recommended approach towards creating the package for ACLs and porting them to different instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options. You could for example create content packages with users and groups (always remember to NOT copy the admin user and leave the .token nodes out of the package as well), you could export ACLs with "ACL" packages using ACS-Commons (1) (you could also build these special content packages manually, but that's a whole lot of work as you have to set regexes in your package or add each ACL path manually).

My advice would be to use the AC Tool from Netcentric (2). This tool can import and export ACLs. There are also advanced configuration options (like loops) available.

But using ACS-Commons together with content packages will bring you the same results mainly.

What you should also keep in mind:

Since AEM 6.1 Adobe changed the naming convention for the user nodes. In earlier version they used the user ID as node name, now they generate hashes. So you cannot guess the user's node when you know the user id.

(1): https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/acl-packager.html

(2): https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool

Comment: thanks Oliver, do both these work well with AEM 6.2 ?

Comment: ACS-Commons does for sure (separate download package for 6.2), AC Tool should also work with 6.2.